# I can't add pop3 to mail in Elementary OS?

Tags: settings, pantheon-mail

I can't add pop3 mail.. I don't have IMAP feature in my mail account.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this issue discussed in 2017-2018](https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues/44) POP3 is not supported but may possibly be supported in a future rewrite of the Elementary Mail app.